# Require In Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to unit test a model called `UserModel`. My RSpec code is:

```
# user_model.rb
require 'user_model'

describe UserModel do
   result = UserModel.add("test","test")
   result.should eq(1)
end
```

The line `require 'user_model'` raises an error:

```
ERROR : `./user_model.rb:1: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord (NameError)`
```

Is that line for importing the class `UserModel`?

Comment: Where is `user_model.rb` located in your app exactly? Why aren't you loading ActiveRecord in your test?

Comment: I have it located in the same file as my RSpec test just for testing purposes. How do I load ActiveRecord? Is it require 'ActiveRecord'?

Comment: require 'active_record'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't include your Rails environment in your test system then the results will be unpredictable. A typical test includes `test_helper` at the very least, which by default loads in Rails and sets up the proper database connections.

Every model when created with `rails generate model` will come with a sample test you can customize.

Answer (score 1):

The message indicates you're using the constant `ActiveRecord` but the library that provides it, `activerecord` is not loaded.

If you're using a recent version of RSpec, make sure you've run the rspec generator `rails g rspec:install` to create the standard spec_helper which will load the Rails environment (including activerecord). At the top of you're user_model_spec, you'll just need `require 'spec_helper'`.